# Selenium Key Toggle Chrome Extension

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I have Tunnel Bear working with my selenium chrome window with Python. The only problem is to get it to turn on, you have to use the keys ctrl+shift+u. I tried using the following but it doesn't work. I would prefer using just selenium to accomplish this if possible.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'u')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're sending a series of keys, webdriver performs the following scenario for every of ones:

1. Press *i* key
2. Release *i* key
3. Press *i + 1* key
4. Release *i + 1* key
5. ...

In other words, when you press SHIFT, CTRL has been already released.

For complex actions you are to take care of this detail and keep system keys pressed.

Java code would look like this:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
// Preparations and navigations
Actions a = new Actions(driver)

// CTRL+SHIFT+U
a.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
 .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
 .sendKeys('U')
 .build()
 .perform();
```

Pay attention that the keys remains pressed after the method call, so I'd suggest you to verify the visible effect of pressing the combination and release system keys

```
a.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
 .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
 .build()
 .perform();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I'm wonder if selenium can't toggle chrome extensions.

Comment: Please verify once again: if your extension is uploaded it would listen this key shortcut no matter if that was you or selenium.
But remember that you always have a plan B: to toggle it from chrome://extensions/ page, though you should play with shadow roots there

Comment: I can get other commands to work that require multiple keys with that but won't work with the extension